# how to convert string to int in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

the following code work but the result is null , is anybody help me to find problem, it seems there is problem to convert string to int in final result

```
DECLARE @dp1 varchar
DECLARE @dp2 varchar
DECLARE @dp3 varchar
DECLARE @dp4 varchar

DECLARE @dpp1 int
DECLARE @dpp2 int
DECLARE @dpp3 int
DECLARE @dpp4 int


set @dp1 = 'Emkanat'
set @dp2 = 'Masraf'



if (@dp1= 'Emkanat')
Begin
set @dpp1= 8 
Select Emkanat*@dpp1 as val1 FROM Cardetail
End

if (@dp1= 'Tarahi')
Begin
set @dpp1= 8
Select Tarahi*@dpp1 as val1 FROM Cardetail
End

if (@dp1= 'Sandogh')
Begin
set @dpp1= 8 
Select Sandogh*@dpp1 as val1 FROM Cardetail
End

if (@dp1= 'Masraf')
Begin
set @dpp1= 8
Select Masraf*@dpp1 as val1 FROM Cardetail
End

if (@dp2= 'Emkanat')
Begin
set @dpp2= 7 
Select Emkanat*@dpp2 as val2 FROM Cardetail
End

if (@dp2= 'Tarahi')
Begin
set @dpp2= 7 
Select Tarahi*@dpp2 as val2 FROM Cardetail
End

if (@dp2= 'Sandogh')
Begin
set @dpp2= 7 
Select Sandogh*@dpp2 as val2 FROM Cardetail
End

if (@dp2= 'Masraf')
Begin
set @dpp2= 7 
Select Masraf*@dpp2 as val1 FROM Cardetail
End


SELECT 
Namecar,
(Masraf*@dpp1)+(Sandogh*@dpp1)+(Tarahi*@dpp1)+(Emkanat*@dpp1)+(Masraf*@dpp2)+(Sandogh*@dpp2)+(Tarahi*@dpp2)+(Emkanat*@dpp2)
 as finalresult
FROM Cardetail
```

the variables need to be feed by varchar and then get an int based on character

Comment: Please explain better your aim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with your code is that you did not define the size of your varchar variables. Change your code as given below and you will get your required output. I have defined the varchar size to 100, modify the same according to your data.

```
DECLARE @dp1 varchar(100) 
DECLARE @dp2 varchar(100) 
DECLARE @dp3 varchar(100) 
DECLARE @dp4 varchar(100)
```